# Get less than a week old data in ISO string format in Mongo DB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to get data that is a week old in mongo db

Here is the field I need to check for -

```
{
 _id:821398723913,
 closed_at:"2020-06-10T01:43:59-04:00"
}
```

What I want is to return all objects where closed_at is less than a week old. I have looked online but none of the solutions work.

Edit:

So far I have tried -

```
db.Orders.aggregate([{
            $project: {
                date: {
                    $dateFromString: {
                        dateString: '$date'
                    }
                }
            }
        }, {
            $match: {
                "closed_at": {
                    $lt: lastDayWeek,
                    $gt: firstDayWeek
                }
            }
        }]);
```

and

```
Orders.find({'closed_at':  {
                $gte: new Date((new Date().getTime() - (15 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)))
            }, 'cancelled_at': null}).sort({_id: 1});
```

I need monday to monday I am trying to figure it out with $isoWeek but have had no luck so far

Comment: Please post all the solutions that you have tried that didn't work.. so that others don't post that same answer again.

Comment: `15 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000` why are you using `15` here when you need only 1 week old data?

Comment: I tried to increase the range just to see if I would get any result

Comment: Here `dateString: '$date'` it should be `closed_at` with timezone if needed & then `$match` !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out a solution using palash's answer

```
let beforeOneWeek = new Date(new Date().getTime() - 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 * 1000)
            , day = beforeOneWeek.getDay()
            , diffToMonday = beforeOneWeek.getDate() - day + (day === 0 ? -6 : 1)
            , lastMonday = new Date(beforeOneWeek.setDate(diffToMonday))
            , lastSunday = new Date(beforeOneWeek.setDate(diffToMonday + 6));


        const orders = await Orders.aggregate([
            {
                '$addFields': {
                    'created_at_iso': {
                        '$toDate': '$created_at'
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                $match: {
                    'created_at_iso': {
                        $gte: lastMonday,
                        $lte: lastSunday
                    }
                }
            }
        ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
db.Orders.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "closed_at_iso": {
        "$toDate": "$closed_at"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "closed_at_iso": {
        $gte: new Date(new Date() - 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
      }
    }
  }
])
```

The issue here is date field is actually a string, we need to convert it first to an `ISODate` format and then `$match` operator works fine.

---

**Edit:**

To get data between last week Monday and this Monday, you can try:

```
var start = new Date(2020, 5, 1), // last monday
    end = new Date(2020, 5, 8);   // this monday

db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "closed_at_iso": {
        "$toDate": "$closed_at"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "closed_at_iso": {
        $gte: start,
        $lte: end
      }
    }
  }
])
```

If you want to make it dynamic we can easily get last Monday and this Monday like:

```js
function getMonday(d) {
  d = new Date(d);
  var day = d.getDay(), diff = d.getDate() - day + (day == 0 ? -6:1);
  return new Date(d.setDate(diff));
}       

var start = getMonday(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - 7))
var end = getMonday(new Date())

console.log(start)
console.log(end)
```

Comment: Hey, is there a way I can get it from monday to monday instead of last 7 days?

Comment: Not getting this properly. Can you share some examples of the collections you have and what is the expected output based on "monday to Monday" filter?

Comment: it is thursday today, I meant I need data from Last week as in last monday to this monday instead of last 7 days.

Comment: That is easy. You can simply use $gte & $lte operator for that.